# Is my approach wrong? I'm confused with NodeJS, MongoDB, Joi, Bcrypt

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt, joi

I have some problems with NodeJS(ExpressJS), MongoDB, Joi Validation Module and Bcrypt.

I have User API router and User Model.
My User Model is This:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [3, 'Adınızın Karakter Sayısı Uygun Değildir. Minimum 3, Maksimum 50 Adet Karakterden Oluşabilir.'],
        maxlength: [50, 'Adınızın Karakter Sayısı Uygun Değildir. Minimum 3, Maksimum 50 Adet Karakterden Oluşabilir.'],
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                return /^[A-Za-zıİüÜğĞşŞçÇöÖ ]+$/.test(v);
            },
            message: 'Uygun Formatta İsim Giriniz. (Geçerli Karakterler: a-z, A-Z, boşluk karakteri.)'
        },
        match: [/^[A-Za-zıİüÜğĞşŞçÇöÖ ]+$/, 'Uygun Formatta İsim Giriniz. (Geçerli Karakterler: a-z, A-Z, boşluk karakteri.)']
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [3, 'Soyadınızın Karakter Sayısı Uygun Değildir. Minimum 3, Maksimum 50 Adet Karakterden Oluşabilir.'],
        maxlength: [50, 'Adınızın Karakter Sayısı Uygun Değildir. Minimum 3, Maksimum 50 Adet Karakterden Oluşabilir.'],
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                return /^[A-Za-zıİüÜğĞşŞçÇöÖ ]+$/.test(v);
            },
            message: 'Uygun Formatta Soyisim Giriniz. (Geçerli Karakterler: a-z, A-Z, boşluk karakteri.)'
        },
        match: [/^[A-Za-zıİüÜğĞşŞçÇöÖ ]+$/, 'Uygun Formatta Soyisim Giriniz. (Geçerli Karakterler: a-z, A-Z, boşluk karakteri.)']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
        minlength: [3, 'Kullanıcı Adınızın Karakter Sayısı Uygun Değildir. Minimum 3, Maksimum 30 Adet Karakterden Oluşabilir.'],
        maxlength: [20, 'Kullanıcı Adınızın Karakter Sayısı Uygun Değildir. Minimum 3, Maksimum 30 Adet Karakterden Oluşabilir.'],
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                let re = /^\w+$/;
                return re.test(v);
            },
            message: 'Uygun Formatta Kullanıcı Adı Giriniz. (Geçerli Karakterler: a-z, A-Z, _.)'
        },
        match: [/^\w+$/, 'Uygun Formatta Kullanıcı Adı Giriniz. (Geçerli Karakterler: a-z, A-Z, _.)']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                let re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
                return re.test(v);
            },
        message: 'Uygun Formatta E-Posta Adresi Giriniz.'
        },
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Uygun Formatta E-Posta Adresi Giriniz.']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Şifrenizi Girmeniz Gerekmektedir.'],
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 1024
    },
    elo: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        required: false,
        default: 0
    },
    rank: {
        type: Number,
        min: -1,
        required: false,
        default: 0
    },
    registerDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }
});
```

And this is Joi Validation Schema:

```
const Schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).regex(/^[A-Za-zıİüÜğĞşŞçÇöÖ ]+$/),
    lastname: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).regex(/^[A-Za-zıİüÜğĞşŞçÇöÖ ]+$/),
    username: Joi.string().required().min(3).max(25).regex(/^\w+$/),
    email: Joi.string().required().min(3).email(),
    password: Joi.string().required().min(5).max(255),
    elo: Joi.number().default(0).min(0),
    rank: Joi.number().default(0).min(-1),
    isAdmin: Joi.boolean().default(false)
};
```

This is sample User:

```
_id:5b47aae43cf7710e7047c033
elo:0
rank:0
isAdmin:true
name:"Furkan"
lastname:"Taştan"
username:"praaven"
email:"furkantastan@superonline.com"
password:"$2b$10$4xKTxmQnV5mnGrCccpQsY.A8j5ACCdmCHIihDdW0NXmcOcRCcwwPq"
registerDate:2018-07-12 22:24:20.778
__v:0
```

I'm confusing on Update API Router.

```
router.put('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const errorId = validateUserId(req.params.id);
        if(errorId.error) return res.status(400).send({'Hata': errorId.error.details[0].message});
        const { error } = validateUser(req.body);
        if(error) return res.status(400).send({'Hata': error.details[0].message});
        const salt = await bcyript.genSalt(10);
        const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            name: req.body.name,
            lastname: req.body.lastname,
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: await bcyript.hash(req.body.password, salt),
            elo: req.body.elo,
            rank: req.body.rank,
            isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin
        }, { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' });
        if(!user) return res.status(404).send({'Hata': 'Belirtilen ID\'ye Sahip Kullanıcı Bulunamadı.'});
        res.status(200).send(_.pick(user, ['_id', 'name', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'elo', 'rank', 'registerDate', 'isAdmin']));
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(400).send({ 'Hata': e.message.replace(/(Validation failed|email|username|phone|team)/gi, v => arrayMap[v]) });
    }
});
```

The problem is, why I need every Update User's password? I don't want User's password, i want to use it on optional. I think, my `Update Router` is wrong, I'm new on NodeJS RESTful API Coding, can you help me with the true of it's?

Thanks, have a good day!

Comment: Ummh.. So, you want to update the password only if it is been modified?

Comment: @B_CooperA Yeah, the same. I just removed `.required()` on password Joi Schema. After, I made an if condition to my PUT Method, for, if(password defined in payload) update user's datas with password, else, update user's datas without password. And I solved this problem with this, for now. Is this good or there is better one approach? Thanks...

Comment: I posted an answer. Just hoping I understood your problem correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already validating the password field at the `Schema` level in here:

```
password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Şifrenizi Girmeniz Gerekmektedir.'],
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 1024
    },
```

so no need to re-validate it with `required()` inside `JOI` schema.

Since you are using `Mongoose`, you could use `pre` functions inside your `userSchema`. Like this:

```
/**
 * Hash password with blowfish algorithm (bcrypt) before saving it in to the database
 */
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified
    if (!user.isModified('password'))
        return next();

    // password will be hashed only if it has changed
    user.password = bcrypt.hash(user.password, bcrypt.genSalt(10));
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is genuinely because of the `required()` that you've put up in your JOI Schema.

As a solution, you have several ways of doing this. You may wish to expose another API to specifically deal with the nuances of passwords and username. In this manner, you end up creating two separate JOI schemas to deal with both the different situations - of changing a password when really needed, and when updating the details ( I am not sure if moving passwords back and forth whilst updating details is a nice idea ).

Addendum : Even with that, I observe that you are actually not doing any transformations here ( except the password ) over the data whilst passing it from the request body to the database model - and I am not sure why would you wish to validate this data twice, for that instance ( remember you have turned on the `runValidators` switch whilst updating as well ).

Comment: Yes, I don't really need to use JOI, yea?

Comment: @n3pixowe You may use either JOI validation OR the Mongoose Schema validation whilst updating. Needn't do it twice at the same data at the same instant yeah.